# The stack overflow error comes when i crete the object of the class in the other class

Tags: c#

```
    public bool update(registrationcommon objreg)
    {
        Userdl objuser = new Userdl();
        try
        {
          return update(objreg);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you thought about your question and what your method does?

Comment: Aside from the recursive call problem you have, there's absolutely no point in code like `catch (Exception e) { throw e; }`. Don't catch an exception if you're not going to handle it and just rethrow it. You'd be just as well off letting the exception bubble up automatically. (Also, when you *do* rethrow, omit the `e` part of the statement.)

Comment: There's not much right about that code snippet you've shown us, it makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

Well yes, it would. Your method is calling itself unconditionally, assuming that `Userdl` is a subclass or implementation of `registrationcommon`. (You should think about improving all your names, by the way.)

How do you ever expect that to terminate? Presumably you meant to call a *different* `update` method - so think about which method you want to call, and how you should call it. Is it a method in a different class? A method in the same class but with different parameters?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're recursively calling `update` functions without stop:

```
public bool update(registrationcommon objreg)
{
    // ...
    return update(objreg);
    // ...
}
```

You have to terminate it at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you call recursive your method without an exit condition - that's a problem!

Answer (score 0):

Each `update` calls `update`, which calls `update`, which...

Every time you call a method, your current location gets pushed onto the stack. In the normal case, when you return from your method call, you "pop" from the stack and go back to where you were. However, if you do this in a loop such as your example, eventually the stack overflows. Hence the term, "stack overflow".